# Can I deploy multiple frameworks for an application on heroku?

Tags: heroku

I read that heroku is a polygot platform: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar#polyglot-platform

Does it provide advanced routing such that I could do this:

```
sample1.heroku.com                   // rails
 www.customdomain.com

sample1.heroku.com/another-path/     // node.js
 www.customdomain.com/another-path

sample2.heroku.com/api/             // java
 api.customdomain.com/
```

So the above is for a single application that uses:

1. rails
2. nodejs
3. java

Also, each framework runs at a particular path, and the java works on a subdomain.

Is this possible with heroku?

Comment: Pretty sure you will still need 3 applications (the "multi" buildpack notwithstanding; see https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) because an app can only have one HTTP listener (via the `web` process type). Getting a second web listener (the Node app) and doing reverse proxy from the Rails app would be tricky because of the dynamic nature of dynos and the limits on port binding within Heroku. I imagine the path of least resistance is to use nginx, HAProxy or Apache as a reverse proxy from an EC2 instance in the same AWS region.